# There are two pages display on screen but only one page in the code?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am newbie with `Rails` and trying to make a page which can link some pages, I mean from this page to another page, as you can see in this picture. I want link the page location and the page faction from the page course.

Here is my code

```html
<body>
<nav>
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
  <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i> 
</a>
<ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li><a href="#!"  <%= courses_path %>">Courses</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!" <%= pages_location_path %>">Location</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!" <%= link_to "faction", pages_faction_path %>Faction</li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
<ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
<li><a href="<%= courses_path %>">Courses</a></li>
<li><a href="<%= pages_location_path %>">Location</a></li>
<li><%= link_to "faction", pages_faction_path %>Faction</li>
</ul>
<%= yield %>
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
  var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems, options);
});
// Or with jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.sidenav').sidenav();
});
</script>
</body>
```

As you can see, in this code I wrote only 3 links, one to the page named "course", one to the page named "location" and one to the page named "faction", but here is what I got

[Picture about my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii6oX.jpg)

As you can see in this picture, I got two pages named "faction".
Could you please explain for me about this problem ? And tell me about the solution of this case ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Issue with your code is on following line
`<a href="#!" <%= link_to "faction", pages_faction_path %>Faction</li>`

Either use link tag or anchor tag. because you are using both tag faction prints two time on screen. please follow below code.

1. `<li><%= link_to "faction", pages_faction_path %></li>`
2. `<li><a href="<%= pages_faction_path %>">Faction</li>`